# What is the expression of following signal in terms of unit step and unit ramp?

Tags: signal

Please help me to find the expression of the following signal

[image: signal][image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Ask a clear question, show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: I have added my solution.now plz check if it is wrong

Answer (score 3):

A hint for you:
How do you represent a gate pulse using step function and what will you multiply with it to make it a ramp function ?

Comment: Please give a solution .i have also done it.but can't be sure about it

Comment: what was your solution ?

Comment: @farihasneha, not a chance. You edit your question and post your workings and solution. This work is for you to do.

Comment: -a delta(t+a)+r(t+a)-r(t-a)-au(t-a)

Comment: Do you believe that an impulse signal, having infinite amplitude but finite area, will help get your amplitude to -a ? Maybe you didnt take that hint seriously.

Comment: :( plz give the solution then i will understand

Comment: @farihasneha pls stop your nonsense :(